# When I click on the "Export CSV" button, I get an error Cannot read property 'get' of null

Tags: reactjs, export-to-csv, react-bootstrap

I am using ReactJS, Bootstraptable.  I am trying to implement exportcsv.  At this point, I have merely attempt to copy the basic set up as outlined in storybook.

However, when I click on the export csv button, I get the following error:
csv.js:120 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null

Here is my table (sorry for the formatting)

```
<PaginationProvider pagination={ paginationFactory(paginationOption) }> 
{({paginationProps,paginationTableProps}) => (
<div>   
<ToolkitProvider keyField="id" data={ products } columns={ columns } exportCSV>
{props => (
<div>
<ExportCSVButton { ...props.csvProps }>Export CSV!!</ExportCSVButton>
<hr />
<BootstrapTable className={ prodTableClass } headerClass={ headerClass }
noDataIndication={ noDataFunction }
exportCSV={true} striped hover
keyField="id" data={ products } columns={ columns }
filter={ filterFactory() } 
{ ...paginationTableProps } />              

{paginationProps.dataSize > 0 && <PaginationListStandalone { ...paginationProps  } />}
{paginationProps.dataSize > 0 && <SizePerPageDropdownStandalone { ...paginationProps }/>}
{ paginationProps.dataSize > 0 && <PaginationTotalStandalone { ...paginationProps } />}
</div>)}                    

</ToolkitProvider>
</div>
)}
</PaginationProvider>
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is with pagination. For some reason it does not let me paginate the table while having this export capability... :(

Comment: Does anyone know how to integrate pagination and exportcsv into bootstraptable?